# Splitting Exsheets Answers into Two Lines

Tags: exsheets

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%%exam stuff
\usepackage[load-headings]{exsheets} %need to have exsheets.cfg in the same folder
\SetupExSheets{
  headings = runin-nr ,
  headings-format = \normalsize ,
  %solution/print = true %get solutions printed after questions
  counter-format = 2-qu. %\penumber-question number. is the counter format. 
}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newlist{choices}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[choices]{itemjoin = \hspace{0.65in},before=\hspace{0.125in},label=(\Alph*)}
%%exam stuff

\newcommand{\itemamount}{0.5in}

\begin{document}
\setlength\itemindent{\itemamount}
\begin{question}[type = exam]
\hspace{0.125in}Question........\par 
\end{question}

\begin{choices}
\item Yah
\item Yah2
\item Yah3
\end{choices}\par 
\begin{choices}
\setcounter{enumii}{4}
\item Yah4 
\item Yah5
\end{choices}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there any way that I can get the second line of the `choices` to align with the first line of `choices` (e.g., the As and Bs should align) and get the second line of `choices` to continue as (D) and (E) instead of (A) and (B)? I tried researching into counters, but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `exsheets` you should be using the facilities of `tasks` package that is loaded by `exsheets` by default. Just define a new task by

```
\NewTasks[counter-format=(tsk[A]),label-width=4ex,before-skip=0.125in,
        item-indent = 4em]{choices}[\choice](3)
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%%exam stuff
\usepackage[load-headings]{exsheets} %need to have exsheets.cfg in the same folder
\SetupExSheets{
  headings = runin-nr ,
  headings-format = \normalsize ,
  %solution/print = true %get solutions printed after questions
  counter-format = 2-qu. %\penumber-question number. is the counter format.
}

\NewTasks[counter-format=(tsk[A]),label-width=4ex,before-skip=0.125in,
          item-indent = 4em]{choices}[\choice](3)

\begin{document}
\begin{question}[type = exam]
\hspace{0.125in}Question........\par
\end{question}

\begin{choices}
\choice Yah
\choice Yah2
\choice Yah3
\choice Yah4
\choice Yah5
\end{choices}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For more details on customizing your list, refer to `tasks` documentation.

Comment: Could you tell me how to decrease the space between "Yah" and (B) to half of the width it is currently? I have tried playing with the properties in the `tasks` documentation but usually end up with badboxes.

Comment: @Clarinetist If you add more text in place of Yah, then it will be alright. Or you can increase the number of columns. The space is actually `column-sep`.